# Wi-Fi on Ubuntu Server 16.04 (connection problems)

Tags: 16.04, networking

I see that a lot of previous people have had this problem, but I've looked absolutely everywhere. I followed every example that I could find, and the same error every time. I can not get any sort of internet connection to Ubuntu Server 16.04 at all. Here is the output of `lshw -class network`:

```
*-network
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: RTL8111/8160/0411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., LTD
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
    logical name: enp1s0
    version: 07
    serial: 70:54:d2:e2:16:7d
    size: 10Mbit/s
    capacity: 1Git/s
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp lii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
*-network DISABLED
    description: Wireless interface
    product: RT5390R 802.11bgn PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Ralink corp.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
    logical name: wlp2s0
    version: 00
    serial: b8:76:3f:5f:d6:ac
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.0-87-generic firmware=0.34 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
    resources: irq:17 memory:fea00000-fea0ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet dhcp

auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet static
address 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
wpa-ssid ZENTA
wpa-psk blahblah
```

When I try to `sudo service networking restart`, I get an error. This is the logs:

```
/etc/networking/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant: 120: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant: cannot create /dev/stderr: No such device or address
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to bring up wlp2s0.
networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
networking.service: Unit entered fail state.
networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

By the way, I had to manually type all this out, so there might be a spelling error or two. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: "DISABLED" usually means that there is a hardware switch or key combination that is set to disable the wireless radio. Confirm: `rfkill list all`. Also, it there a typo? You can't use 192.168.0.1 for the address if you are trying to connect to a router whose gateway address is 192.168.0.1. The selected address must be outside the DHCP range in the router.

Comment: @chili555 For some reason, I started up the server today and all two of the network devices are enabled. Also, that is not a type, I did put that within my network configuration. I didn't know exactly what to put there, so I just guessed my gateway address. I changed the `address` part to `192.168.0.95` to try it out, but I received the same error: `Failed to bring up wlp2s0`.

Comment: @chili555 I just tried to run `rfkill list all`, and it says that the rfkill package isn't installed.

Answer (score 0):

Two different devices with different hardware addresses can't use the same address on the same network. In this case, your wireless access point (router) is 192.168.0.1, you suspect. Your wireless device, your RT5390R 802.11bgn PCIe Wireless Network Adapter, is not allowed to use the same address.

First, verify that the gateway (router) address is 192.168.0.1. Can you verify with other devices; that is computers, phones, iPads, etc., on the same network?

Next, the address for static IP addresses must be outside the pool used in the router for DHCP. Please see this example: https://www.voipmechanic.com/dlink_pics/dlink-airwireless1.jpg

In this example, the DHCP range is set to x.100 to x.199. We can therefore safely use a static IP address in the range of x.2 to x.99. For example, I might use a static address of 192.168.0.50.

Either log on to the administrative pages of the router and verify the range, or, if this is impossible, note the addresses of other devices connected to it by DHCP and guess. For example, suppose that the various laptops, phones, iPads, etc. are all given addresses from 192.168.0.5 to 192.168.0.25. It is reasonable to guess, therefore, that an address of 192.168.0.150 is available.

Next, your interfaces file lacks required DNS nameserver addresses. I suggest that you amend the `interfaces` file to something like:

```
#auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet dhcp

auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet static
address 192.168.0.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
wpa-ssid ZENTA
wpa-psk blahblah
```

Note that I have commented out `auto enp1s0` so that it doesn't start automatically. The goal here is wireless. If you need to start it after boot, you can always:

```
sudo ifup enp1s0
```

Finally, stopping and restarting networking is deprecated. Instead, please do:

```
sudo ifdown wlp2s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp2s0
```

Did you get the requested address?

```
ip addr show
```

Are you connected?

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: This is my DHCP configuration within my router's admin panel: https://i.imgur.com/fnFvMn7.png. For example, would my `address` in the network configuration be `192.168.0.102`?

Comment: Also, when I try to restart the `networking` service, I get a lot of `WPDMA TX/RX busy` errors. (I know you told me not to, but I need to refresh the networking configuration)

Comment: In your administration page, DHCP is set to use the *entire* available range, leaving no room at all for static. Can you change it so the range is, for example, 192.168.0.2 to 192.168.0.100? Then it would be safe to use 192.168.0.107. As for networking, if I told you that it's no longer useful, why would you use it *anyway* and complain about its errors?? Don't you believe that ifdown/ifup refreshes the network configuration?

Comment: I changed the range to use `192.168.0.2` to `192.168.0.100` and changed my configuration to use `192.168.0.107`, but I am still receiving `busy` errors.

Comment: Where are the `busy` errors? In ifup?

Comment: Yes, it is in ifup.

Comment: Also, when I use `ifdown wlp2s0`, it says `ifdown: interface wlp2s0 is not configured`

Comment: Please run: `sudo ifdown wlp2s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp2s0` and paste the result here and give me the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Here's the output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26097323/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69617/discussion-between-jacob-gunther-and-chili555).

Comment: Did you find a solution @JacobGunther ?

Comment: @Benjamin Gauthier Nope. I haven't used Ubuntu in a while though, so I haven't looked for a new solution.